# How to change SparkContext property spark.sql.pivotMaxValues in jupyter PySpark session

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Q: How to change SparkContext property spark.sql.pivotMaxValues in jupyter PySpark session

I made the following code change to increase spark.sql.pivotMaxValues. It sadly had no effect in the resulting error after restarting jupyter and running the code again.

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import RowMatrix
import numpy as np
try:
    #conf = SparkConf().setMaster('local').setAppName('autoencoder_recommender_wide_user_record_maker') # original
    #conf = SparkConf().setMaster('local').setAppName('autoencoder_recommender_wide_user_record_maker').set("spark.sql.pivotMaxValues", "99999")
    conf = SparkConf().setMaster('local').setAppName('autoencoder_recommender_wide_user_record_maker').set("spark.sql.pivotMaxValues", 99999)
    sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
except:
    print("Variables sc and conf are now defined. Everything is OK and ready to run.")
```

<... (other code) ...>

```
df = sess.read.csv(in_filename, header=False, mode="DROPMALFORMED", schema=csv_schema)
ct = df.crosstab('username', 'itemname')
```

Spark error message that was thrown on my crosstab line of code:

```
IllegalArgumentException: "requirement failed: The number of distinct values for itemname, can't exceed 1e4. Currently 16467"
```

I expect I'm not actually setting the config variable that I was trying to set, so what is a way to get that value actually set, programmatically if possible? THanks.

References:

> Finally, you may be interested to know that there is a maximum number
>   of values for the pivot column if none are specified. This is mainly
>   to catch mistakes and avoid OOM situations. The config key is
>   spark.sql.pivotMaxValues and its default is 10,000.

Source: https://databricks.com/blog/2016/02/09/reshaping-data-with-pivot-in-apache-spark.html

I would prefer to change the config variable upwards, since I have written the crosstab code already which works great on smaller datasets.  If it turns out there truly is no way to change this config variable then my backup plans are, in order:

- relational right outer join to implement my own Spark crosstab with higher capacity than was provided by databricks
- scipy dense vectors with handmade unique combinations calculation code using dictionaries

Comment: Were you able to get this to work? I'm running into the same problem, and setting spark.sql.pivotMaxValues doesn't seem to work!

Comment: I have the same problem. however I change it but did not affect

Answer (score 0):

*kernel.json*

This configuration file should be distributed together with jupyter
`~/.ipython/kernels/pyspark/kernel.json`

It contains SPARK configuration, including variable *PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS* - list of arguments that will be used with `spark-submit` script.

You can try to add `--conf spark.sql.pivotMaxValues=99999` to this variable in mentioned script.

PS
There are also cases where people are trying to override this variable [programmatically](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/issues/154#issuecomment-203105983). You can give it a try too...